# iCloud and Comcast Email

Tags: data-synchronization

I have been using MobileMe to sync emails from my two comcast email addresses from Outlook on my PC to my iPhone and iPad.  With MobileMe being turned off at the end of this month it will be necessary to migrate to iCloud.  It was my understanding that I would no longer be able to get email from my two Comcast email addresses synced to my iPhone and iPad after moving to iCloud, rather, only email send to me at my me.com email address would only be synced.

Am I correct in assuming that email from my two Comcast email addresses will no longer be synced after MobileMe is gone?

Comment: @nathang, thank you for your comment.  To clarify, I have had the Comcast email accounts on my PC and iPhone since I bought the iPhone, so setting up the email account has been done.  To answer your question, Comcast is POP not IMAP. That being the case, will my Comcast emails continue to be synced to my iPhone and iPad after mobile.me disappears?   Thanks.

Comment: As long as you have setup your Comcast accounts as individual mail accounts on your iPhone, they will continue to sync as before.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by sync. Yes your comcast mail will not be synced to iCloud.
However you can read the comcast email on the IPad etc (assuming hat comcast is IMAP).

To set up the Comcast mail go to Settings->Mail then add accounts. Googolling for `Comcast iphone email` provides more help including [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCyozkPIVgY).